# Showing $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+a_k} \ge\frac{n}{1+\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n} a_k}} .$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, jensen-inequality

Suppose  $$a_1 , a_2 , ... , a_n$$ are given real numbers that are *greater or equal than $1$*.

Prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+a_k} ≥ \frac{n}{1+\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n} a_k}} $$
I tried using Bergstrom but the it results the opposite inequality(less or equal). And I tried writing them as $$a_1 = x_1 + 1$$ so I can work on positive real numbers but it gets really complicated.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: "Nice looking"?????   What does that mean or have to do with anything?  or the double exclamation points?

Comment: The exclamation points are there because you should keep in mind they're greather or equal to 1. Nice looking because it's nice/simple looking but pretty hard I think.

Comment: "Nice looking because it's nice/simple looking..."  Do you realize how vacuous that statement is?  And that adding double exclamation points (on a trivial matter) is ungrammatical?

Comment: I don't know I just wanted an idea on the inequality I didn't focus on the title.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is not the same as $a_n \geq 1$ (re: your edit) -- in fact this does not hold if we only assume $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $a_k = e^{b_k}$ for some $b_k \geq 0$. Then use Jensen’s inequality on the convex function $$x \to \frac{1}{1+e^x}.$$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is a convex function for $x\geq0$ and use Jensen.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Tatarusan Marius You are welcome!